# How to insert a space and comma between selenium-extracted words into excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I'm new to Python.
Currently, extracting Music Genres from Google.
Using Python, selenium, and pandas

i.e) I extracted a genre from
https://www.google.com/search?q=Anything%20I%20Want%20genre

The music has genres of 'Pop music', 'Pop rock', and 'Pop'

Now, I'm writing it into an excel file.

> if i % 10 == 0:
> song_excel.to_excel('./Song_Genre.xlsx',index=False)

However, currently, it wrote in the excel like this: Pop musicPop rockPop

When I double click the excel's cell, the cell automatically separates into multiple rows of words such as;

Pop music

Pop rock

Pop

From the code, the result shows as below

> print("genre: {}".format(genre))

genre :

Pop music

Pop rock

Pop

How do I write extracted words to excel in series in one cell?: (Goal)
(with space, and with comma)
=> Pop music, Pop rock, Pop

--- adding some codes

> start_row = 2
> song_excel = pd.read_excel('./Song_Genre.xlsx')
>
> for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(start_row,len(song_excel))):
>
> ```
> if song_excel.iloc[i,2] != 0:
>     pass
> elif song_excel.iloc[i,2] == 0:
>     song_name = song_excel.iloc[i,0]
>     url = song_excel.iloc[i,1]
>
>     driver.get(url)
>
>     genre = None
>
>     try:
>        genre = driver.find_element(by = By.XPATH, value = "/html/body//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' KKHQ8c ')]").text
>     except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
>
> if genre != None:
>          song_excel.iloc[i,2] = genre
>          pass
> if i % 10 == 0:
>          song_excel.to_excel('./Song_Genre.xlsx',index=False)
> ```

Best,

Comment: Look at my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the string contains some '\n' which is interpreted by excel as newline. So you need to replace the value with desired value. Use:

```
gen = '''Pop music

Pop rock

Pop'''

# Solution
gen = gen.replace('\n', ', ')
temp=pd.DataFrame({'test':[gen]})
```

Note that without replacing, the excel behaves as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but I confront this error message. (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' )

Comment: Is it within a for loop? Maybe sometimes there is not genre in the page so the None happens. In that case you can just try...except that special case.

Comment: Yes.. It is within a for loop.. and sometimes there are No genres in the page.. Thanks though!